# Laravel 5.2.2 and Entrust error call to undefined method

Tags: laravel, entrust

When I am using latest Laravel 5.2.2 and Entrust ("zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev") I face this error and not sure how to solve this:

```
Call to undefined method Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::hasRole()
```

I tested this code on HomeController.php

```
use Entrust;

class HomeController extends Controller
{ 


    public function index()
    {
        if (Entrust::hasRole('admin')) {
            echo "string";
        }

        return view('home');
    }
}
```

This is my config/app.php service provider

```
Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class
```

config/app.php facade alias

```
'Entrust'   => Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::class
```

I also already generate the model needed

[image]

[image]

[image]

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 11):

I have same issue, here are the steps I have taken to solve the issue

In your .env file change to cache array

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

and dont forget to run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: I get the problem even using `array` or `memcached` (see https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/679#issuecomment-293126444).

Comment: Try after clear you catch and reset your config using artisan

Comment: Ohh here was my mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462365/laravel-cache-store-does-not-support-tagging/37463070?noredirect=1#comment73760715_37463070  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It seems all the steps is correct, and I just need to clear the cache with `php artisan config:cache`

And if you face an error like below

```
BadMethodCallException in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\Repository.php line 380:
This cache store does not support tagging.
```

You need to change in .env this line to array

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

Comment: i had same error. i have tried by changing CACHE_DRIVER=array in .env file and also in config/cache file 'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'array') but i have got new error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'App\Permission' not found `  can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open environment file of your laravel change CACHE_DRIVER=file to CACHE_DRIVER=array and save.

Now try your CLI command.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel drivers does not support tagging. To solve this, go to your `.env` file and change

```
Cache_driver=file
```

to

```
Cache_driver=array
```

and run

```
php artisan config:cache
```