# Laravel cache store does not support tagging

Tags: laravel

I am getting this error since I installed **Zizaco\Entrust** on my Authentication Routes.

```
BadMethodCallException: This cache store does not support tagging.
```

I had few known issues and I had to change some config options and that is the reason I am getting this error.

What does this error relate to so that I can find the problem and fix it instead of finding the code I modified?

Thanks

Comment: What cache driver do you use?

Comment: using file cache driver

Comment: Use Redis instead. It supports tagging.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Cache tags are not supported when using the **file** or **database** cache drivers. The **Entrust** package probably uses them somewhere. You should be ok if you change it to **array**, **memcache** or **apc** for example.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache#cache-tags

Comment: Probably best not to switch to `array` as that's just a cache for a single request used mainly for testing.

Comment: hey guys can you help me? i am facing same problem. I used redis driver. But still same error.

Comment: You use Redis driver and you get **This cache store does not support tagging.**?

Comment: I get the problem even using `memcached` (see https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/679#issuecomment-293126444).

Comment: @Ryan in `cache.php` even if you change the key `'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'memcached')` its still going to take it from your `.env` file. So either change it to `'default' => 'memcached'` in `cache.php` or change it from your `.env` file.

Comment: @TheFallen Wow, I cannot *believe* the brain skip I had. Thank you. I forgot about my `.env`. My `.env` had the default cache driver as `file`, and I was using `memcached` only in certain cases. When I changed my `.env` to use `memcached`, Entrust worked. Thanks. P.S. Running `php artisan config:clear` is probably necessary too after changing the config.

Answer (score 73):

Laravel `file` and `database` drivers don't support `tags`.

What you need to update, to fix this issue is simply changing the **cache driver** from **file** to **array** in your `.env` (located in root folder) file as below.

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Apparently, in some project, Redis was configured, but the config setting was left set as "file" accidentally, and setting it to "redis" solved the issue as it's even supported natively: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/cache#redis

Answer (score 24):

open `.env` file and
change

```
  CACHE_DRIVER=file to CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

Or add this line showing below

```
  CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

After that go your command prompt or open the terminal then type

```
  php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this command in your command prompt

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 6):

In Your .env file change

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

To

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

Then run these commands

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

It will work

Comment: From my knowledge i think that cache tags are not supported when using the file  driver. The Entrust package probably uses them somewhere.So it can be canged to array.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Laravel file and database drivers doesn't support tags. What you can do to while developing is change the driver to array in your .env file.
CACHE_DRIVER=array

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is a duplicate of already existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

in your .env file change to cache array

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

and dont forget to run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change `.env`

> CACHE_DRIVER=file

To

> CACHE_DRIVER=array

Answer (score 0):

Cache tags are not supported when using the file or database cache drivers. The Entrust package probably uses them somewhere.

Open `.env` file set

```
 CACHE_DRIVER = array
 SESSION_DRIVER = file
```

> then make command in terminal

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

If you continue having the issue, you should change  your entrust version to

```
dev-laravel-5
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change in **cache.php** the following line from "file" to "array" as well:

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'array')
```

Hope it helps!