# Laravel run package artisan command in controller

Tags: php, laravel-8, vuejs3, laravel-artisan

I need to run this command when user change something in translation file

> php artisan export:messages-flat

I need to add it in may controller

so I'm using this code

> \Artisan::call('export:messages-flat');

but it return error saying that

> The command "export:messages-flat" does not exist.

but when I

> php artisan list

[image]

it's in the list

I also try to run other command

> \Artisan::call('cache:clear');

and it works

this is the package I'm using [link](https://medium.com/@sumeshvasu/laravel-vuejs-localization-with-package-laravel-localization-to-vue-73a87d2eec78)

kindly help me, sorry for may poor english

Comment: Not sure why that isn't working, but according to their documentation you can call `ExportLocalization::export()->toFlat()`. See https://github.com/kg-bot/laravel-localization-to-vue#export-for-npm-localization-packages-like-langjs

Answer (score 0):

The package only allows you to run the commands from the CLI. You can [see from the source code](https://github.com/kg-bot/laravel-localization-to-vue/blob/master/src/LaravelLocalizationServiceProvider.php#L45), they only register the Artisan commands if the application is running from the console.

As an alternative, you can call `ExportLocalization::export()->toFlat()` [according to their documentation](https://github.com/kg-bot/laravel-localization-to-vue#export-for-npm-localization-packages-like-langjs).

Comment: sorry but , I get another error saying.
This cache store does not support tagging.

Comment: This is just a guess but go into `config/laravel-localization.php` and change cache driver from `file` to `array`. I am basing this on https://stackoverflow.com/q/37462365/296555. You may have to clear the cache after making these changes.

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: This cache store does not support tagging. already fix, but the file ll_messages.js didn't compile. but when I run the command in cli, it compile